# what's the difference between Boundingbox and hiresBoundingbox?

Tags: graphics

What's the difference between Boudingbox and hiresBoundingbox in an eps figure?

Comment: *After every use of a bounding box, it is sent to Adobe for recycling. When needed you hire a new one*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original boundingbox only allowed integer multiples of postscript points (although not all systems enforce that) The hiresbounding box allows decimal fractions of a point to be specified.

Comment: And the driver for `graphicx` can use the HiResBoundingBox if so instructed (`hiresbb` option).

Comment: @David Carlisle: Thanks! So, what does ``hires'' mean? (Higher Resolution?)

Comment: Some caution is needed. Bounding boxes are dependent on the resolution (curves, sharp corners, &hellip). If the bounding box is tighter (hiresbb), then the probability of cutting something off is larger.

Comment: @zhimengfan: `HiRes` of `HiResBoundingBox` means "high resolution". Bounding boxes with integer numbers have a resolution of 72 DPI. AFAIK ghostscript uses 4000 DPI as default for its `HiResBoundingBox` calculation of device `bbox`.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek: Great !  :)